# Playing different ps4 games on two different devices using different accounts on each device

Tags: ps4, ps-remote-play

Can I be playing a ps4 game on the tv using my account and my brother using remote play be playing another ps4 game using his account at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible with one PS4.

Remote play allows you to use the PS4 as normal from another device. So if you are already using the PS4 then you can't use it for remote play.

To play seperate games at the same time you need two PS4's.